# Restrict input field not to have same input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table inside which I have several input fields, `iteName`,`unitQty` and `disc%`.

`ItemName` is a jquery autocomplete field so after selecting the text the focus shifts to `UnitQty` and after that when user presses enter I am creating new row same as above

In new row in `itemname` column what I have selected above is also coming which I don't want

The `ItemNames` I am getting is from JSON data So when user again selects the previous data I want to prompt a alert that this name is already present and empty the field

**What I have done**

```js
"use strict";
console.clear()

function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
  const fixed = parseFloat(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [float, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+float).toLocaleString(locale)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}

var CostPrice = "";
var totalAmount = "";
var unitQuantity = 0;
var unitQuantityOnDisc = 0;
var purchaseRateOnDisc = 0;
var purchaseRate = 0;
var totalAmount = "";
var discPercentage = "";
var discAmount = "";
var totalAmountOnDisc = "";
var subTotalOnDisc = 0;
var gstPercentage = "";
var gstAmount = "";
var totalAmountOnGst = "";
var total = 0;
var supplierCode = "";
var totalDiscountAmt = 0;
var totalGstAmt = 0;
var totalUnitQty = 0;
var subtotal = 0;
var totalAfterGrnDisc = 0;
var totalRoundOff = 0;
var totalAfterfreightAmt = 0;
var totalAftercommissionAmt = 0;
var mrpOnDisc = 0;



const tableData = {
  "ALMOND CHBAR~2402": {
    "itemName": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "itemCode": "2402",
    "costPrice": 20.0,
    "gstPercentage": 14.5,
    "mrp": 30.0
  },
  "A BR SB EX~333": {
    "itemName": "A BR SB EX",
    "itemCode": "333",
    "costPrice": 1.0,
    "gstPercentage": 0.0,
    "mrp": 1.0
  }
}


var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(tableData);

function rowappend(tbody) {

  const markup =
    `<tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" class="form-control commantd" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="purRatetd" id="purRatetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commantd" name="unitQtytd">
           </td>
          
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd"class="form-control commantd" name="discPercentagetd" >
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td> 
           <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           
         </tr>`

  $(tbody).append(markup);
  setTimeout(() => $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().focus(), 100);

  $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().autocomplete({
    source: autoCompleteData

  });
  $("[name=itemNametd]").change(function() {
    if (autoCompleteData.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1) {
      $(this).val("");
      alert("chose correct ItemName")

      return false;
    }
  });

}




rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'))


function getValues(row) {
  const search = ($('[name=itemNametd]', row).val()).toString()
  const value = tableData[search];
  CostPrice = value.costPrice;

  if (value) {
    $(row).find("[name=itemCodetd]").val(value.itemCode);
    $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val(format(value.mrp));
    $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val(format(CostPrice));
    $(row).find("[name=discAmttd]").val(value.DiscAmt);
    $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val(value.gstPercentage);
  }

  /*   $("#unitQtytd").click(function () {
       $(this).select();
    }); */
}



function calc(row) {
  unitQuantity = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val() || '0';
  purchaseRate = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val() || '0';
  var mrp = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").text() || '0';
  totalAmount = (parseFloat(unitQuantity) * parseFloat(purchaseRate));

  $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val(format(totalAmount));

}

function calcDiscount(row) {
  unitQuantityOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val() || '0';
  purchaseRateOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val() || '0';
  mrpOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val() || '0';
  subTotalOnDisc = (parseFloat(unitQuantityOnDisc) * parseFloat(purchaseRateOnDisc));
  discPercentage = $(row).find("[name=discPercentagetd]").val() || '0';
  gstPercentage = $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val() || '0';

  discAmount = (parseFloat(discPercentage) / 100) * parseFloat(totalAmount) || 0
  totalAmountOnDisc = (parseFloat(totalAmount) - parseFloat(discAmount))
  gstAmount = (parseFloat(gstPercentage) / 100) * parseFloat(totalAmountOnDisc);
  totalAmountOnGst = (parseFloat(totalAmountOnDisc) + parseFloat(gstAmount))
  total += parseFloat(totalAmountOnGst);
  totalDiscountAmt += parseFloat(discAmount);
  totalGstAmt += parseFloat(gstAmount);
  totalUnitQty += parseFloat(unitQuantity);
  subtotal += parseFloat(subTotalOnDisc);
  totalRoundOff = total - Math.round(total);


  $(row).find("[name=discAmttd]").val(format(discAmount));
  $(row).find("[name=gstAmttd]").val(format(gstAmount));
  $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val(format(totalAmountOnGst));

  $("#unitQtytf").text(format(totalUnitQty));
  $("#discAmttf").text(format(totalDiscountAmt));
  $("#gstAmttf").text(format(totalGstAmt));
  $("#netAmtInput").val(format(total));
  $("#totalAmttf").text(format(total));
  $("#subTotalInput").val(format(subtotal));
  $("#itemAmtDiscinput").val(format(totalDiscountAmt));
  $("#taxAmtInput").val(format(totalGstAmt));
  //   $("#roundOffAmtInput").val(format(totalRoundOff));


}

$(document).on('focusout', (e) => {


  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (e.target.matches("[name=itemNametd]")) { // whene focus is out from itemNametd

    getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)

  }

});

$(document).keypress(function(event) { // here I am trying to create new row when enter is clicked
  const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement
  var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (keycode == '13') {
    alert("presed")
    calcDiscount(event.target.parentElement.parentElement)
    if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
      rowappend(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)

      total = 0;
      totalDiscountAmt = 0;
      totalGstAmt = 0;
      totalUnitQty = 0;
      subtotal = 0;

      $("#tableInvoice tbody tr").each(function() {
        calc(this)
        calcDiscount(this)
      })
    }
  }



});
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]') || e.target.matches('[name=unitQtytd]')) {

    var keycode = e.keyCode || event.e;
    if (keycode == '9') {


      if (!$(event.target).val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }


      total = 0;
      totalDiscountAmt = 0;
      totalGstAmt = 0;
      totalUnitQty = 0;
      subtotal = 0;

      $("#tableInvoice tbody tr").each(function() {
        calc(this)
        calcDiscount(this)
      })


    }

  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container commonDivInvoice">
  <div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
          <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Code</th>
          <th id="mrpth" class="commanth">Mrp</th>

          <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
          <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
          <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
          <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
          <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
          <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
          <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>


        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row tableGrn">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tfootTable">
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td id="itemNametf" class="commantf" align="center">Total ->
        </td>
        <td id="itemCodetf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="mrptf" class="commantd"></td>
        <td id="purRatetf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="unitQtytf" class="commantf"></td>

        <td id="discPercentagetf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="discAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="gstPercentagetf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="gstAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="totalAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
      </tr>

    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

[fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/rzkbwsg7/6/)

Comment: Your snippet gives error

Comment: Why not use .clone?

Comment: @mplungjan please check my fiddle in case snippet gives error

Comment: `ItemName` value is not getting copied to the next row in your example

Comment: @shrys I didn't get you ? I am creating row dynamically each time I press enter

Comment: I did not understand the issue you're facing

Comment: Same error in snippet: "Cannot read property 'costPrice' of undefined"

Comment: @mplungjan you could put that statement inside `if (value)` right below it

Comment: @shrys why would I do that? It's not my code

Comment: @shrys if you have checked my snippet , I am selecting an itemname from itemName field by typing , so when i create a new row and both the row should not have the same itemname i am trying to do

Comment: @mplungjan that error has nothing to do with what I am trying to do, my code is working fine

Comment: @manishthakur So you mean it shouldn't show up in the suggestion, correct?

Comment: @shrys yup correct, check the fiddle i have updated

Comment: @mplungjan check the edit now fiddle is fine

Comment: Still getting the error. Please check the console

Comment: @mplungjan hey if you are going with empty itemname then obviously it is going to show error, I have to handle that error once I got though this issue, anyways that error as nothing to do with the issue I am facing

Comment: I type AAA and then tab and I get the error

Comment: @mplungjan yup you will get that error because AAAA is not present, I have to handle that also I told you will handle that later after finishing this one

Comment: @shrys hey have you found any thing?

Comment: So what do I do to trigger your issue and not an error?

Comment: @manishthakur we could add a property in the json data to check if it already has been put or not and suggest accordingly, JIJOMON K.A answer could work in a way too

Comment: @shrys there autocomplete is not working

Comment: @mplungjan I have edited the snippet as well as the fiddle, now if you type AAAA it shows alet to chose correct name,please check and help me out if you can

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an array with all item names and check the enterd value is present in that array.

Change text box name `itemNametd` into `itemNametd[]`

**Jquery Code**

```
var itemNametd=[];var flag=  'Success';var Message="Success";
   $('input[name="itemNametd[]"]').each(function() {
        $(this).css("border", "");
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
            flag = 'Error';
             Message="Please Enter Value"
        }else{
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), itemNametd) != -1){
         $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
         $(this).val('')
           Message="name is already present"
   flag = 'Error';
                        }else{
            itemNametd.push($(this).val())
            }

        }
    })

    if(flag=='Error'){
    alert(Message)
    return false
    }
```

check this [**Fiddel**](https://jsfiddle.net/tymvqpj3/)

Comment: hey can you edit your fiddle as of my code, I am confused to apply auto complete using the above code you answer, if you get time please edit

Comment: As you can check the JSON of mine I am populating all the keys as itemname in `itemname` field and on choosing that poulating its corresponding data

Answer (score 0):

- You can maintain an array of ItemName. So when user presses enter
  button, make a function call in which check whether entered ItemName
  is already present in list.
- If ItemName is already present in array then show error to the user.
- If ItemName is not present then add it in the array list.